# Emergency stopping of Akka Actor

Tags: java, scala, parallel-processing, akka

I am using Akka framework to control hardware, and in rare cases I need to freeze an actor in a middle of computation. This prevents damage to the hardware. Is there a way of quickly freezing or killing and Actor, even if it is still running a task?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sadly this is not something that the JVM supports. While a Thread is running, for example doing some long running operation, it can not be arbitrarily interrupted (yes, there is a `interrupt()` call however it just sets a flag, and the Thread's user-land code may look at this flag, it's not a forceful interruption). Since Akka Actors utilise Java threads, the same limitation applies to them.

How Actors do help here however is that you can chunk up the work into very small chunks of work, think "steps", and represent them as messages. If you detect you should not proceed further, you simply could stash the messages (or simply no-op on them, instead of performing some action).

It kind of depends what you mean by "freeze". By itself it's not possible, but maybe a very similar effect is achievable?

// The killing part can be done via `context stop self` inside the Actor or by sending a `PoisonPill`, this however is asynchronous and goes through the Actors mailbox - as everything in actor communication.

Comment: I am taking your advice and breaking the process into smaller Akka steps. In between the process can be stopped. Thanks!